# intel xdk lock rotation of screen

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

i am using code to lock Orientation of one of page of my html app, but it seems not working , please guide what am i missing or way to fix it

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);               
function onDeviceReady(){
    intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation('landscape');
    console.log('heyy');
    intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to force a particular orientation on hybridsapps, because its different that you are using titanium or cordova, or if you are developping for Android, iOs or Windows.

I recommend using another perspective: attempts to detect the orientation of the device using JavaScript (for example, triggers an event when resizing the window, and compares the height to width), and display a warning so that only the web is read from the orientation that you want, or apply a transformation of 90 degrees to the body of the website for rotate it with the device.

Another option would be to apply a CSS style for each orientation.

http://jsfiddle.net/pq20rd0g/

```js
function myFunction() {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    var h = window.outerHeight;
    var txt = "";
   if (w < h) {
     txt ="The windows is <b>PORTRAIT</b> mode";
   } else if (h < w) {
    txt ="The windows is <b>LANDSCAPE</b> mode";
   } else {
    txt ="The windows is <b>SQUARE</b> mode";
   } 
   
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<body onresize="myFunction()" onload="myFunction()">

<p>Try to resize the browser window to emule the orientation change.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> this example will not work properly in IE8 and earlier. IE8 and earlier do not support the outerWidth/outerHeight propery of the window object.</p>

</body>
```

I'm sorry about my English.